# Laravel can't return true json response

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, laravel-5, fetch-api

I have a quite simple Laravel controller:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function list()
    {
        return response()->json(['a' => 'hello']);
    }
}
```

When I try to open a corresponding url in browser(I use Google Chrome) it works fine. There is `{"a":"hello"}` response and content type is `application/json`.

But when I receive data via javascript (I use [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)) I see that content type is `text/html`. I checked it in GoogleChrome DevTools and within my code:

```
fetch("/list")
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type')); // => 'text/html'
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) { 

    })
    .catch(function(error){

    });
```

Well I've got the error - `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

I completely don't understand what's happened.

**PS**:

Laravel version - 5.4, PHP Version 7.0.15, XAMPP 3.2.2

Fetch polyfill version - 2.0.3

Google Chrome version - 57.0.2987.133

And yes, it sounds strange, but in MS Edge v.20.10240 it works fine.

Comment: Have you looked at the dev tools to see what the request responds with? It's possible the server is returning html with the data

Comment: "I checked it in GoogleChrome DevTools" - content type is `text/html`. So, the question is why? It should be `application/json`.

Comment: try checking the response if it is available (same thing you did before but there should be a response tab next to the header), whenever I see this error it tends to be from the server responding with html for some reason or another

Comment: Have you read the content of the HTML response the server is sending? Maybe it’s an error page with an error message of some kind that indicates there’s some problem/failure on the server side in trying to serve the response. Also, check the server-side web-server/PHP error logs to see if some error is getting logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the `session` auth for all my routes. So, the problem was there.
`api` routes like below help me:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/list', 'ApiController@list');
```

One more think. I added `api_token` for all my requests like described [here](http://bootstrapdojo.com/rest-api-laravel-5-4-with-token-authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the header of your request with content type of json. I dont know about polyfill but this is how i would do it with jquery

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: 
                error: 
            });
```

Comment: Thanks @victor! Postman makes it clear. I use auth for the requested url. And for some reason I've got authorization page within response in Chrome but not in Edge. Anyway, now I know where the problem is.